# How can I use an interface in a main controller of an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, interface, controller

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project where I have one solution **dotnetmvc** which contains two projects:

1. dotnetmvc (main project)
2. Service (contains an interface for it).

My problem is that when I am trying to use an interface from the Service project within a controller of the main project then I am not getting a reference to the interface.

Please refer to the below screenshots:

Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show your IUser code with namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of 2 reasons why this would happen:

1. your interface is not public. make sure you add public.

```
public interface IUser
{
 .......
}
```

2. the project `dotnetmvc` is on a lower dotnet version as the `Service` project

- Right click on each project, select properties and make sure dotnet version is the same on both projects

Comment: Yes you are right, My interface is not Public, Now it`s working fine and proper. Thankyou very much for helping me thanks a lot.